# LaTeX3 Error: Command '\sc' already defined!

Tags: errors, latex3, xparse

Please can someone explain to me why I'm getting the following compiling error

`LaTeX3 Error: Command '\sc' already defined!`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
  \NewDocumentCommand{\ch}{om}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
       \chapter{#2}
    }{ 
       \chapter{#2}\label{ch:#1}
          
    }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\sc}{om}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
       \section{#2}
    }{ 
       \section{#2}\label{sc:#1}
          
    }
}

\begin{document}

\ch{AAA}
\sc{BBB}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Because `\sc` is already defined in the `book` class (it's the deprecated version of `\scshape`).  You can redefine it with `\RenewDocumentCommand`

Comment: P.S.: don' use these “shortcuts” for such common commands.  They only _seem_ to make your life easier, but you are actually shooting yourself on the foot.  Quick example:  how do you do `\section*{title}` or `\section[short]{long}` with those shortcuts?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response

Comment: I second @PhelypeOleinik's advice. Is there any real advantage in `\sc[label]{title}` over `\section{title}\label{sc:label}`? Maybe, but just as a far possibility, if you have over 100 sections, but you lose in generality and semantic nonetheless.

Comment: apart from the error from `\sc` you are adding lots of white space tokens in these macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\sc` is a legacy font command based on `\scshape` that  is used in the `book` class for compatibility with LaTeX2.09. You could use another name such as `\Sc` but beware such shorthands make it harder to use standard section features such as the `*` form for the unnumbered variant, and the optional argument for the table of contents version of the header.

Also as you are adding a lot of white space (in a standard context not in `\ExplSyntaxOn`) these space tokens can affect the output, consider

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
  \NewDocumentCommand{\ch}{om}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
       \chapter{#2}
    }{ 
       \chapter{#2}\label{ch:#1}
          
    }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Sc}{om}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
       \section{#2}
    }{ 
       \section{#2}\label{sc:#1}
          
    }
}

\begin{document}

\ch{AAA}


aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa a
aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa. a
\Sc{BBB}

aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa a
aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa. a {} {}
\section{BBB}

aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa a
aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa. a
\section{BBB}

\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Where the `\Sc` version is producing the heading as if the previous paragraph ended with additional space as shown in section 2 as opposed to the intended layout produced by `\section` in section 3.